# Spring Security ignoring context-path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/api/data")
String response(){

}
```

application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/v1
```

Spring secuity

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyMatcher("/v1/**").authenicated()
```

Here authentication is not happening. I believe, **spring-security is ignoring the context-path** thats been configured in the application.properties. Why is spring-security ignoring the context path. How to fix this?

[image]

For the above image, I expected a 401 since the v1/** is supposed to be authorised

This is working fine,

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyMatcher("/**").authenicated()
```

Comment: spring (web) security is (normally) configured "per servlet", and has the same "context root"...and your security configuration refers relatively to it! (try in browser: `.../v1/v1` ;)

Comment: or in security config: `.authorizeRequests().anyMatcher("/**").authenicated()`

Comment: so context-path is supposed to work? i have updated my question

Comment: context-path is set on tomcat, or the underlying server, then all other is configured in your application. So as pointed out, your config now says "../v1/v1...."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn ON the debug for Spring Security, then you would understand what's happening.

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
```

When,

```
server.servlet.context-path=/v1
```

Generated Request:

```
Request received for GET '/api/data':

servletPath:/api/data
pathInfo:null
```

When,

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/v1
```

Generated Request:

```
Request received for GET '/v1/api/data':

servletPath:/v1
pathInfo:/api/data
```

Go with servlet-path for what you are trying to implement...

Comment: I observe that `AntPathRequestMatcher` compares against the URL, specifically `(servletPath + pathInfo)` of an `HttpServletRequest`. In a similar vein, is there an alternative **PathRequestMatcher** that allows comparison against the value of the `server.servlet.context-path` property?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm working with Spring Security 6 + Spring Boot 3. In the `application.yml` I set this configuration to set the root path for the API:

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api/v1
```

I have a very simple class to check CORS policy **before** starting to work with anything else in the API, which is:

```
@Controller
public class AliveController {

    @GetMapping("/alive")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAlive() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(200).body("Everything OK!");
    }
}
```

And in my class `SecurityConfiguration`, which is annotated with `@Configuration` and `@EnableWebSecurity`, I put these two methods annotated with `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/alive").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .securityMatcher("/**")
                .build();

    }
```

Note that I put this `/alive` endpoint to bypass authentication requirement, also I referenced it without root path (`/api/v1`). Also, note that I have in the cors method a parameter `Customizer.withDefaults()`, that is invoking the default method to configure cors named in Spring by default as `corsConfigurationSource()`. So, Spring will search for a method with that name and I named that way. Then, I set my own ruled cors in that method in the same class, something like:

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        // corsOrigins, allowedHeaders, allowedMethods, exposedHeaders
        // are String arrays set as private final in the class
        config.setAllowedOrigins(List.of(corsOrigins));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(List.of(allowedHeaders));
        config.setAllowedMethods(List.of(allowedMethods));
        config.setExposedHeaders(List.of(exposedHeaders));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
```

---

Also, I'm noticed something about paths (something that's got me all over the place). If you set in the `spring.mvc.servlet.path` property the value `/api/v1`, cors policy supposes you'll set that policy within /api/v1, so you don't need to set again in the rules in `securityMatcher("/**")` or in `source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);`. The policy will get those `/**` considering there's a root preceding `/api/v1`.

Trying in the terminal with cors origin `http://localhost:3000`...

```
~ http get :8080/api/alive Origin:http://localhost:3000
HTTP/1.1 200
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Allow, X-Get-Header
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 14
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 11 Mar 2023 08:07:11 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

Response:

```
Everything OK!
```

Trying with another port...

```
~ http get :8080/api/alive Origin:http://localhost:3001
HTTP/1.1 403
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 11 Mar 2023 08:09:14 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

Response:

```
Invalid CORS request
```

Please, be aware of the `List.of(corsOrigins)`, `List.of(allowedHeaders)`, `List.of(allowedMethods)` and `List.of(exposedHeaders)`, which are Lists coming from something like:

```
private final String corsOrigins = "http://localhost:3000";

private final String[] allowedMethods = {"GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"};

private final String[] allowedHeaders = {"Authorization", "Accept", "Accept-Language", "content-type", "Requestor-Type", "X-Requested-With"};

private final String[] exposedHeaders = {"Allow", "X-Get-Header"};
```

It's been hours of my life I won't get back with this thing hehe.

Hope it helps.